# PHP Startup: Unable to load dynamic library 'ssh2.so'

Tags: php, codeigniter, suitecrm

Hello recently I Upgraded my SO from 16.x to 22.04 also I upgraded the PHP version at same time from 7.2 to 7.4 .. 8.x and I installed some extensions for PHP, but im having issues with SSH2.so im getting this error :

[image]

also my openssl version is :
[image]

not sure if it's related, somebody can help me to fix this issue?

cheers!

Comment: I'm assuming that you actually need to use the extension. You may simply need to install the extension module via `apt install php8.1-ssh2` or similar. Are you just using the base 22.04 PHP packages? Or a 3rd party repo like deb.sury.org?

Comment: Please do not use screenshots of your code or error messages and do not link to external sources. Screenshots are hard to read on mobile devices, they cannot be searched and none of us can copy, paste and run an image, links can get obsolete. Code should be included as text in the question itself. For more on this see 
[**Why may I not upload images of code**](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-not-upload-images-of-code-on-so-when-asking-a-question/285557#285557) 
on SO when asking a question?

Comment: Look at the path in the error message `/usr/lib/php/20190902/ssh2.so.so` and the error message `No such file or directory`... now try to think about it

Answer (score 0):

This is just a warning, it's just telling you that it's not finding the SSH2 library. To solve it, just comment where there is extension=ssh2 in php.ini and restart your apache

Comment: what if the SSH library is required?

Comment: This library is very specific, it is unlikely that it will be required in an application. But if you really need to use it, just install it using yum install php-ssh2 or apt-get install php-ssh2